# OpenXML - Bullet Points get transformed to numbered list when merging documents

Tags: c#, ms-word, format, openxml

I have two documents that I try to merge partially.

I take some parts from document A that are inside a RTF content control and copy all child elements of the `sdtContent` of the content control to another `sdtContent` in document B using AppendChild and CloneNode(true) (deep cloning):

```
foreach (var srcChildElement in sourceDocumentSdtContentBlockNode.ChildElements)
{
    targetSdtContentBlock.AppendChild(srcChildElement.CloneNode(true);
}
```

The problem is, that if the content (list items) in my source document A is formatted with bullet points the result in document B will be numbered list items.

Why isn't the resulting style like in the source when I clone it? I thought it would just keep its style as I don't manipulate it. In document B there seems also no to be a formatting issue. I can manually insert bullets or a numbered list without a problem.

I even created two completly new word documents and the same thing happend, so it is surely not some issue with the existing files.

***Update:***
*I found out that there is a separate numbering definition in a document (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee922775(v=office.14).aspx) which is not part of the node I copy. When I clone the node this information is not included at it is in a separate numbering definition. Is there a way to copy a node to a new document and tell it to retain the numbering styles from the numbering definition? The other option would be to manually check if the cloned node contains a `numPr` element and if yes to extract also the definition (including changing and reassigning the IDs) - would prefer a less complex way to copy an element and hope there is one :-)*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did manage to solve this. As already mentioned the Numbering information is stored in a separate part (or file inside the document zip):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee922775(v=office.14).aspx

From the `NumberingDefinitions` (in NumberingPart) of the source I copied the necessary (where there is a `numPr` inside a paragraph). To the target file by lookup up the `numId` of the `numPr`.

I cloned the `num` element and also the corresponding `abstractNum` element to the target. Doing this I also replaced the IDs (incremented all by 1 using the existing element IDs in the target) like `numId`, `abstractNumId` and `nsid` (hex value) to make sure there won't be any conflicts.

Was a bit work but very doable.

Comment: By the way: I would highly recommend to use the OpenXML PowerTools to merge documents (with the DocumentBuilder class). With the PowerTools you don't have to invent the wheel again...

Comment: Do you have some example code for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have this code anymore but I believe I did it similar to this question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600564/openxmlpowertools-documentbuilder-merging-documents-on-a-seperate-page