# Merge 2 Word Document using c#

Tags: c#, merge, ms-word, openxml, document

I am trying to merge 2 word documents in binary format, however, it only gets the first document. The resulting document should have all elements from each source document included with formatting.

Here is the code so far. Using OpenXml by the way.

```
private static byte[] Merge(byte[] dest, byte[] src)
{
    string altChunkId = "AltChunkId" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();

    var memoryStreamDest = new MemoryStream();
    memoryStreamDest.Write(dest, 0, dest.Length);
    memoryStreamDest.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(memoryStreamDest, true))
    {
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        Paragraph para = new Paragraph(new Run((new Break() { Type = BreakValues.Page })));
        mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(para, mainPart.Document.Body.LastChild);

        //Insert the source file into the target file using AltChunk
        AlternativeFormatImportPart chunk = mainPart.AddAlternativeFormatImportPart(
        AlternativeFormatImportPartType.WordprocessingML, altChunkId);

        using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream())
        {
            mem.Write(src, 0, (int)src.Length);
            mem.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            chunk.FeedData(mem);
        }

        AltChunk altChunk = new AltChunk();
        altChunk.Id = altChunkId;
        mainPart.Document.Body.InsertAfter(altChunk, mainPart.Document.Body.Descendants<Paragraph>().Last());
        mainPart.Document.Save();

        return memoryStreamDest.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "merge"?

Comment: You also never use `altChunk` -- presumably that's unintentional? You also don't save the document properly.

Comment: Combining 2 word documents to make it as one file.

Comment: Right, but combining how? Should the result contain all the elements in document 1, followed by all the elements in document 2? If so, why are you messing around with AlternativeFormatImportTypes? What happens if the documents have different styles, etc? This is going to be hard if the documents have lists as well, since you need to manage the numbering part of the document.

Comment: That's what I am planning to do, should have both elements included with formatting. Do you have something to recommend? Thanks!

Comment: Related: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a1449c87-3ae4-404f-abdf-f8bc098e9048/join-multiple-word-documents-into-one-open-xml?forum=aspgettingstarted and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600564/openxmlpowertools-documentbuilder-merging-documents-on-a-seperate-page. Using the AlternativeFormatImportTypes approach could work looking at the first link, but you'll need to fix the obvious errors in your code first

Comment: Manage to make this one worked.

Comment: @Yuno - *Manage to make this one worked* - in that case might you add a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) letting us know how you resolved your problem?  Thanks!